# Is there a way to reuse std::atomic on a given int32_t?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex, atomic

I have an `int32_t` with an initial value 42. Now I want it to be atomically accessed by multiple threads.

```
#include <atomic>

using namespace std;
int32_t* pn{};

int main()
{
    pn = getPtrFromMmap();    
    assert(42 == *pn); // note that *pn is mapped to a disk file

    // How to make the following two threads access *pn atomically?
    std::thread{[&]{ (*pn)++; }}.detach(); 
    std::thread{[&]{ (*pn)++; }}.detach();
}
```

It is not a trivial task to write a correct atomic operation class. So, I tried to use `std::atomic` to achieve my goal, but failed.

**Is there a way to reuse `std::atomic` in such a case?**

Comment: Instead of using `std::atomic`, why not simply use other thread synchronization primitives, like mutexes and locks?

Comment: If you are 100% sure the variable can't change by an external force, just copy it in an atomic and copy back when everything is finished. Otherwise, you already have a race condition, so you need to update the underlying code

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, `std::atomic` is more performant than `std::mutex`.

Comment: @JVApen, copy-write-restore is not acceptable, because the memory address is mapped to a disk file, that is, in pagecache. Even if the process crashes, the data in pagecache will be ok; while the copy in a variable will be lost in such a case.

Comment: So you want an atomic reference to a volatile integer?

Comment: @JVApen, I would not say "atomic reference." That makes it sound as if it enables some kind of atomic operation on a reference variable (e.g., like how a `std::atomic<int*>` object enables atomic operations on the pointer) What the OP wants is a type that contains a reference/pointer, and performs the atomic operations on the _target_ of the pointer/reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Think of `std::atomic` as roughly

```
template <typename T>
class atomic {
    T value;
public:
    // a bunch of member functions
};
```

I.e. a `std::atomic<int32_t>` *contains* an `int32_t`.

What you need is a

```
template <typename T>
class atomic_ref {
    T & ref;
public:
    // a bunch of member functions
};
```

Such a type is not a member of `std::`.

In C++17 `std::atomic<std::reference_wrapper<T>>` is guaranteed to be valid, but it doesn't help here. Operations on the referent are not atomic.